# Setting text objects to be centered on the canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have several text objects that I would like to have programmatically centered on my fabric.js canvas (instead of having to eyeball and program each it.) I am using v. 1.7.20 of fabric.js. What should I add to my constant so that each object is centered vertically?

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");
canvas.setHeight(616);
canvas.setWidth(446);

const text = {
  fontSize: 27,
};

// Text that should be centered
canvas.add(new fabric.IText("Line 1", {
  ...text,
  top: 25,
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.IText("Line 2", {
  ...text,
  top: 55,
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.IText("Line 3", {
  ...text,
  top: 85,
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.IText("Line 4", {
  ...text,
  top: 115,
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.IText("Line 5", {
  ...text,
  top: 145,
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.IText("Line 6", {
  ...text,
  top: 175,
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.IText("Line 7", {
  ...text,
  top: 205,
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.IText("Line 8", {
  ...text,
  top: 235,
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.IText("Line 9", {
  ...text,
  top: 265,
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.IText("Line 10", {
  ...text,
  top: 295,
}));
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.20/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `canvas.centerObjectH(obj)` to center an object horizontally. Here is doc [centerObjectH](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#centerObjectH)

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");
canvas.setHeight(616);
canvas.setWidth(446);

const text = {
  fontSize: 27
};

// Text that should be centered
canvas.add(new fabric.IText("Line 1", {
  ...text,
  angle:25,
  top: 25,
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.IText("Line 2", {
  ...text,
  top: 55,
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.IText("Line 3", {
  ...text,
  top: 85,
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.IText("Line 4", {
  ...text,
  top: 115,
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.IText("Line 5", {
  ...text,
  top: 145,
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.IText("Line 6", {
  ...text,
  top: 175,
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.IText("Line 7", {
  ...text,
  top: 205,
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.IText("Line 8", {
  ...text,
  top: 235,
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.IText("Line 9", {
  ...text,
  top: 265,
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.IText("Line 10", {
  ...text,
  top: 295,
}));
canvas.forEachObject(function(obj){
 canvas.centerObjectH(obj)
 obj.setCoords();
 canvas.renderAll();
})
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.20/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add the following to my constant. Seemed to do the trick. If anyone has ideas of how to improve this, I'd love to know.

```
left: 223,
originX: center,
originY: center
```